# Evaluation of an improper integral: $\int_0^\infty \frac{t\sin{t}}{u^2+t^2\,}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I want to calculate the integral below for positive $u$.
$$\int_0^\infty \dfrac{t\sin{t}}{u^2+t^2}dt$$
Wolframalpha gives me a simple answer : 
$\dfrac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}$.

but I cannot approach to that.
Can anyone solve above without using complex integral (ex.residue integration.. because I'm beginner of analysis)?

Thanks.

Comment: ${1 \over 2}\,\pi\exp\left(-\left\vert u\right\vert\right)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**. Let's consider the  [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems) of $\displaystyle I(a):=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx$. We have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}\left(I(a)\right)(s)&=\mathcal{L}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx\right)(s)
\\& = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}e^{-as}\:da\:dx
\\&= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s}{(x^2+1)(s^2+x^2)}\;{dx} 
\\&= \frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}
\end{aligned}
$$giving
$$
I(a)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2(s+1)}\right) =\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-a},\qquad a>0, \tag2
$$ then *by differentiating* $(2)$ *with respect to* $a$, one gets
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-a},\qquad a>0. \tag3
$$  as given by *Wolfram alpha*.

Comment: Understand it, but how can I justify the exchange of improper integral between second and third equalities??

Comment: @JinmooYou This may be justified by the following inequalities: $\left|\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}\:dx \right|\le \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac1{x^2+1}\:dx<\infty$ and $ \left|\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(ax)e^{-as}\:da\right|\le \int_{0}^{\infty}1\cdot e^{-as}\:da<\infty$ which give the right to use Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

**Contour integration**
We are going to evaluate the integral using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the upper semi-circle
$$\gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where }  \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (0<t<\pi) $$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t \sin t}{u^2+t^2} d t=& \frac{1}{2} \Im \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{t e^{t i}}{u^2+t^2} d t \\
= & \frac{1}{2}  \Im\oint_\gamma \frac{z e^{z i}}{u^2+z^2} d t \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \Im\left[2 \pi i\operatorname{Res} \left(\frac{z e^{z i}}{u^2+z^2}, z=ui\right)\right] \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \Im\left(2 \pi i \lim _{z \rightarrow u i}(z-u i) \frac{z e^{zi}}{z^2+u^2}\right) \\
= & \frac{1}{2} \Im\left(2 \pi i \frac{(u i) e^{(u i) i}}{2 u i}\right) \\
= & \frac{\pi }{2} e^{-u}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Your first equality should be $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t\sin t}{u^{2}+t^{2}}dt = \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Im}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{te^{ti}}{u^{2}+t^{2}}dt$. Still gave the +1 though!

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it is fixed and updated.